# How to implement INotifyDataErrorInfo for Datarow

Tags: silverlight, inotifydataerrorinfo

i have a datarow class that implements **`Dynamicobject and INotifyPropertyChanged and INotifyDataErrorInfo`**

Also have a property called **`'GridData'(datarows)`** in this class that is bound to xaml for displaying in the grid

May i know how to implement **`public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)`**

correctly since **`'GridData'`** property can have many property bags

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//This is your row... more or less.
public class GridData : DynamicObject, INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
   private Dictionary<string, object> _propertyValues = new Dictionary<string, object>();

   //this object holds your errors.
   private Dictionary<string, List<ValidationResult>> _errorsContainer = new Dictionary<string, List<ValidationResult>>();

   //when this fires it notifies the UI the errors of this object have changed.
   public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

   //This tells the UI there are errors.
   public bool HasErrors
   { 
      get { return this._errorsContainer.Count > 0; }
   }

   //this allows the UI to retrieve all errors for a given property
   public IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
   {
      return this._errorsContainer[propertyName];
   }

   //This sets the error for a given property and fires the errors changed event
   protected void SetError(string propertyName, IEnumerable<ValidationResult> errors)
   {
      List<ValidationResult> existingErrors;

      if(this._errorsContainer.TryGetValue(propertyName, out existingErrors) != true)
      {
         this._errorsContainer[propertyName] = errors.ToList();
      }
      else
      { 
         existingErrors.AddRange(errors);
      }

      this.RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyName);
   }

   //This clears the errors for a given property
   protected void ClearErrors(string propertyName)
   {
      this._errorsContainer.Remove(propertyName);
      this.RaiseErrorsChanged(propertyName);
   }

   //This raises the event that the errors of this object have changed.
   protected void RaiseErrorsChanged(string propertyName)
   {
      if(this.ErrorsChanged != null)
      {
         this.ErrorsChanged(this, new DataErrorsChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
      }
   }

   //inherited from dynamic object this returns the value for a given property.
   public override bool TryGetMember(GetMemberBinder binder, out object result)
   {
      //this gives you the name of the property.
      string name = binder.Name;

      return _propertyValues.TryGetValue(name, out result);
   }

   //inherited from dynamic object, this is called when a property is set.
   public override bool TrySetMember(SetMemberBinder binder, object value)
   {
      string propertyName = binder.Name;

      List<ValidationResult> validationErrors = new List<ValidationResult>();

      //store the value in the propertyValues regardless if it is erroneous.
      _propertyValues[propertyName] = value;

      //this is where you test the value of the property.
      if(value /* whatever condition you use to test it */)
      {
         //no errors so update the ui.
         this.ClearErrors(propertyName);
      }
      else
      { 
         //there was an error for this value.
         ValidationResult result = new ValidationResult("The value is wrong.");

         //add the error to the list of errors for this property
         validationErrors.Add(result);

         //update the error container telling it there are errors for this property.
         //fire the errors changed event, and update ui.
         this.SetError(propertyName, validationErrors);  
      }

      return true;
   }

}
```

Comment: I use **public class GridData : DynamicObject,INotifyDataErrorInfo** and may i know where to do the validation? do i need to validate here **public object this[string index]**?

Comment: actually public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged is always null, even if the errors collection is changed

Comment: When setting a property value, you would validate the value. If the value is bad, you would call the set error method, passing in the string index (your property name) and also a List of validation result. The bindings to this object use the ErrorsChanged event which will fire when you set the error.

Comment: Thanks, Could you also post the xaml lines? how this dynamic object is bound?

Comment: I am using a converter in the xaml binding. I bind the entire object(GridData) to the path of binding and use value converter to get the value that i need (using index and parameters of the converter) Looks like the binding framework reads the Griddata property in this case and not individual properties of GridData.

Comment: mine is <TextBlock Text='{Binding Path=GridData, Converter={StaticResource variableConverter}, ConverterParameter=Id|Label|Items|Column1}' />

Comment: You have to set the binding path to the property you want to display in the text block.

Comment: I corrected my binding property path. Now its like Path=[myPropertyName].Now what happens is that when setting the property thru indexer and validating and finally raising the error event, GetErrors method is triggered.  The parameter is 'Item [myPropertyName]' and so Errorchanged event is null.Any help? Why is it in Item []?

Comment: You don't have to use this complicated stuff. All you have to do is: <TextBlock Text='{Binding Id, Path=GridData}' /> Please read the documentation of what DynamicObject is and it's usage. Since you already know the property names - Id, Label, Items, Column1, etc.. there is no need to use an indexer.

Comment: I tried this today and am getting  The property 'System.Windows.Data.Binding.Path' is set more than once.

Comment: ! do i need to set binding to TwoWay inorder to show the validationsummary of the error?  Rightnow, i see validaiton tooltip but not the validationsummary.